# Error with regex in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate my textbox on `keypress` event. As I am newbie with jquery, I searched on google and found one jquery plugin named 'limitkeypress'.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#title").limitkeypress({ rexp: /^[A-Za-z]*$/ }); 
});
```

Plugin library is:

http://brianjaeger.com/process.php

It's giving me the following error

> $("#title").limitkeypress is not a function

When I checked the library on jsfiddle it shows me dozens of errors. Is there any other validation library or plugin?

**EDIT** *Thanks everyone for your valuable comment. Finally I got the solution. Though I was including file correctly. but don't know Y it was not working. I wrote **jQuery.noConflict();** and all the problem is solved. What exactly it work. Please let me know, though I read but doubt still I have doubt.*

Comment: Did you try their demo on a simple page to see if it worked or if it's just your application? Did you make sure their JS is included and downloaded properly in Firebug?

Comment: Yes I have download its one of version. didn't download min.js....Should I do that? And its working on site..

Comment: If you're including some other library besides jQuery on your page such as ExtJS or prototype, some of the function calls may overlap. The `noConflict()` function namespaces the jQuery calls so that no accidental overloading will occur.

Answer (score 1):

regexp is ok:
`'buGaGa'.match(/^[A-Za-z]*$/);` 
`$("#title").limitkeypress is not a function` probably you forget to inlude library or wrong path.
Check it in Firebug( Net -> All ) lib must be highlight in black, not red.

Comment: Nopes it doesn't shows me anytype of error using firebug.. Even this error is shown by firebug..

chrome shows me..#object has no method limitkeypress..

Comment: add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://brianjaeger.com/jquery.limitkeypress.js"></script>` if error still exists, may be plugin is incompatible with your jquery version, on site of plugin using jquery `1.3.2`

Comment: Problem still continue..Ya its written for jquery1.3.2 showing on site and now I am using. Jquery's latest version how can I make it compatible..?

Comment: Look at Andy's answer, there is no compatibility problem. I advise to you to remove all javascript except limitkeypress, may be error not in plugin.

Comment: I did, I don't know y its not working even I have included correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Made a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tTASy/
plugin seems to work fine.

Check your path to the script. if you paste a link to your page we could help you more specifically.

Comment: how can I show u that... join on onlinemeeting. I will show you that how it work..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery like this without the plugin..

```
$("#your_textbox").keypress(function() {
  var length = this.value.length;
  if(length >= MIN && length <= MAX) {
    $("#your_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#your_validation_div").hide();
  } else {
    $("#your_submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#your_validation_div").show();
  }
});
```